# Show that $p(x)$ has a root in the interval $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n} \in \mathbb R$ satisfy

$$\frac{a_{0}}{1} + \frac{a_{1}}{2} + \frac{a_{3}}{2} + ... + \frac{a_{n}}{n+1} = 0.$$

Show that $p(x) = a_{n}x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + ...+ a_{0} $ has a root in $(0, 1)$.

Since it is a polynomial, I know it is continuous on all of $\mathbb R$. So I thought to use IVT, so I want to show that the range of $p(x)$ on $(0, 1)$ is not exclusively positive values nor it is exclusively negative. My goal is to show that $\sum_{}{p(x)} = 0$ using the previous sum. But I don't know how to handle the input $x$ for $p$. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apply Rolle's theorem to $q(x)=\int_{0}^{x}p(t)dt$ on $[0,1]$. You have that $q(0)=\int_{0}^{0}p(t)dt=0$ and $q(1)=\int_{0}^{1}p(t)dt=\frac{a_0}{1}+\frac{a_1}{2}+...+\frac{a_n}{n+1}=0$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803680/if-a-0-a-1-ldots-a-n-in-r-and-fraca-01-fraca-12-cdots-fraca-n

Comment: @Gary yes please. Thank you so much.